# Wordpress add_rewrite_rule redirection match GET variable not passing through to custom template

Tags: user-roles, rewrite-rules, profiles

**My target:**

1. Create a page template in theme (*page-expert.php*) following the guide [Page
   Templates](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/).
2. Create a blank page with the template.
3. The above page will show the profile information for certain users (by
   custom role 'expert' created by [add roles](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_role)).
4. The default Wordpress link for a profile is http://mysite/author/expert-name. But I want the link
   http://mysite/writer/expert/[expert-nickname] should show the
   profile for user roles 'expert' user expert-nickname

It is more or less an implementation of [add_rewrite_rule](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule).

**What I did:**

Template file, role and page (page_id=211,
    slug=http://[mysite]/writer/expert) is created accordingly.

Redirection managed (through class *myExpert* initiation in function.php) and permalink settings updated:

```php
    class myExpert extends myWriters{
    public function __construct(
    add_filter('init', array($this, 'set_expert_link_base'));
    add_filter("expert_link", array($this, 'fix_expert_link')); //For now, this changes the link of all author profiles. I'll look into it later.
    }

    function set_expert_link_base()
        {
            add_rewrite_tag('%expert%', '([^&]+)', 'expert=');
            add_rewrite_rule('^expert/([^/]*)?','index.php?page_id=211&expert=$matches[1]','top');
        }

    function fix_expert_link($link)
        {
            if($link){
                return str_replace("author","expert",$link);
            }
        }
    }
```

**Problem:**

When calling http://mysite/writer/expert/[expert-nickname], the redirection to the page is taking place, but the get variable is not getting processed in *page-expert.php*. The following do not contain any index 'expert'. (Global $wp_query and $wp)

1. `$wp->query_vars`
2. `$_REQUEST`
3. `$wp_query->query_vars`

```php
$exp_slug= get_query_var('expert');
```

ia blank

```php
    add_filter('request', array($this, show_req_vars()));
    function show_req_vars($vars)
    {
    print_r($vars);
    return $vars;
    }
```

Outputs:

> Array (
>       [page_id] => 211 )

What am I doing wrong/missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `$query` parameter from `add_rewrite_tag`. Your rewrite tag registration will look like this: `add_rewrite_tag('%expert%', '([^&]+)');`.

The phrase in the rewrite rule may be `'^expert/([^/]+)/?'`, but it was not the reason for the problem.